# Can you store an instance of a jQuery plugin in a variable rather than associated with an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

If person is a jQuery plugin can you create an instance and then use the plugin functionality rather than associate it w/ an HTML element? For example:

```
var $person = $.person(); //person plugin
```

Then do things like $person.add() etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with most (the vast majority) of jQuery plugins, no...they're plugins *because* they do things with/to elements.

Outside that contenty, they wouldn't make much sense...then they would be just ordinary functions, and should be used that way, really with no ties to jQuery, though they may make use of it.